# Método construtor para calcular a idade

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

Estou fazendo um aplicativo de cadastro de cliente bem simples gostaria de saber como programar um método que calcula e retorna a idade (em anos) a partir do atributo AnoNascimento. Sei como fazer, por exemplo, um "public static int CalculaIdade(DateTime x)", mas para fazer um método construtor para calcular a idade a partir do ano de nascimento realmente não entendi.

Abaixo coloquei um print da tela e a parte do código que é interessante analisar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    List<Pessoa> listcadastro = new List<Pessoa>();

    public class Pessoa
    {
        private string nome;
        private string endereço;
        private string ano_nascimento;
        private string telefone;

        public string Nome
        {
            get
            {
                return nome;
            }

            private set
            {
                nome = value;
            }
        }

        public string Endereço
        {
            get
            {
                return endereço;
            }

            private set
            {
                endereço = value;
            }
        }

        public string Ano_nascimento
        {
            get
            {
                return ano_nascimento;
            }

            private set
            {
                ano_nascimento = value;
            }
        }

        public string Telefone
        {
            get
            {
                return telefone;
            }

            private set
            {
                telefone = value;
            }
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, string ano_nascimento, string telefone)
        {
            this.nome = nome;

            this.endereço = endereço;

            this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;

            this.telefone = telefone;

        }
    }


private void bt_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa(txt_ano.Text, txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, txt_telefone.Text));

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = listcadastro;
}

private void novoMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_nome.Enabled = true;
    txt_ano.Enabled = true;
    txt_endereco.Enabled = true;
    txt_telefone.Enabled = true;

    if (bt_pjuridica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_registro.Mask = "00,000,000/0000-00";
    }

    if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_registro.Mask = "000,000,000-00";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Na realidade o construtor não irá calcular a idade, a menos que você tenha uma propriedade Idade e o construtor atribua o valor a esse propriedade.

```
    public class Pessoa
    {
        private string nome;
        private string endereço;
        private int ano_nascimento;
        private string telefone;
        private int idade;

        public string Nome
        {
            get
            {
                return nome;
            }

            private set
            {
                nome = value;
            }
        }

        public string Endereço
        {
            get
            {
                return endereço;
            }

            private set
            {
                endereço = value;
            }
        }

        public int Ano_nascimento
        {
            get
            {
                return ano_nascimento;
            }

            private set
            {
                ano_nascimento = value;
            }
        }

        public int Idade
        {
            get
            {
                return idade;
            }

            private set
            {
                idade = value;
            }
        }

        public string Telefone
        {
            get
            {
                return telefone;
            }

            private set
            {
                telefone = value;
            }
        }

        public Pessoa(string nome, string endereço, int ano_nascimento, string telefone)
        {
            this.nome = nome;

            this.endereço = endereço;

            this.ano_nascimento = ano_nascimento;

            this.telefone = telefone;

            this.idade = DateTime.Now.Year - ano_nascimento;

        }
    }
```

O seu botão salvar terá uma rápida alteração

```
private void bt_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa(int.Parse(txt_ano.Text), txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, txt_telefone.Text));

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = listcadastro;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você fez vários métodos (como fazia antes) para retornar e setar os valores nas propriedades, porém não há necessidade de utilizar assim você pode escrever as propriedades dessa forma:

```
public string nome { get; set; }
//ou um set privado
public string idade { get; private set; }
```

fica mais fácil de entender. E retornar a idade em anos ficaria assim:

```
public static int calcularIdade(DateTime x)
{
  TimeSpan idade = DateTime.Now - x;
  //divide a quantidade de dias por 365.25(por causa dos anos bissextos) e da um cast pra int, não tem erro
  int anos = (int)(idade.Days / 365.25)
  return anos;
}
```